# How to handle K8S CRD CRUD requests by only one instance of an operator

Tags: kubernetes, crud

I have a K8S CRD and a custom operator for that, which is scaled to several replicas. On a new CRUD request for that CRD all of the operator instances are triggered. Is there a way to somehow round robin CRUD requests or to mark them as being processed by a particular instance of the operator? I guess if I add an external DB to mark particular request as being processed by a particular instance it will work, but I don't wont to introduce more complexity than needed.

Comment: The controller-runtime https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-runtime library is built so that events that would trigger the controllers are taken from a queue. Different instances of the controllers get different events from the queue, so only one instance is getting the event. What are you using to build the controller?

Comment: I'm using the io.fabric8 java sdk.